# Laravel: can't see the variable value other than 'radio'

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, foreach, laravel-blade

I am trying to loop through an array with a foreach statement. I get the array from an API, not mine. I use the foreach from Laravel in the blade.
Somehow in my blade if I go thru the array, each one has a type, it only sees the "radio" type. No checkbox or textarea. Wonder why and what I can do to fix it.

```
<form action="/sendForm" method="post">@csrf
            @foreach($survey['data']['formCategories'] as $category)
                <h3 id="{{$category['name']}}">{{$category['name']}}</h3>  <!-- Enquete -->
                <hr/>

                @foreach($category['formQuestions'] as $question)

                @if($question['type'] === 'header' || $question['type'] === 'text' || $question['type'] === 'date')
                    <!-- Don't show -->
                    @else

                        <div>
                            <p class="questions">{{$question['name']}}</p>

                            <fieldset id="{{$question['id']}}" class="form-group">
                                @foreach($question['formOptions'] as $answer)
                                    @if($question['type'] === "textarea" || $question['type'] === "paragraph")
                                        TextArea
                                    @elseif($question['type'] === "checkbox")
                                        Checkbox
                                    @elseif($question['type'] === "radio")
                                        Radio
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
            <input type="submit" value="Sent" class="submit-btn" id="versturen">
</form>
```

In the end I want to show according to type a form input. So if the type is textarea show a textarea, if it's checkbox make a checkbox, and the same with radio.

I am sorry for any bad grammar, and I know it's not the best question, but I didn't know how else to ask.

EDIT

Api Response

```
name: '',
formCategories: [ //Different Categories
    0:  name:''
    formQuestions: [ //Questions
    0:  name: '',
        type: '',   //Is either Radio, Checkbox or TextArea
        formOptions: [ //Possible answers if necessary, empty if not needed.
        0:  name: ''
        ]
    ],
],
```

EDIT 2

dd with a type textarea:

```
array:7 [
name: '',
formQuestions: [
    name: '',
    type: 'textarea',
    ]
]
```

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the API response, maybe that will help? EDITED RESPONSE I'm not sure what the cause of the problem is but I think you should check to see if you're able to access the value `$question['formOptions'` in your for-loop by dumping `dd($question['formOptions')`. If it isn't accessible, then that may be the cause. Otherwise, let us know what the dumped value is. You can consider sharing the structure of API responses as well (I see you already did).

Comment: can you just dd($question) before foreach and show us the response?

Comment: @DEEPAK I have tried that also, It doesn't work to dd $question

Comment: Before your form, add  `{{ dd($question); }}`, and you'll *dump die* the object. Doing so will not magically fix anything - but doing so and giving us the results can help us help you.

Comment: @Qirel If I would do this before the form the $question will yet excist

Comment: Sorry, I ment inside the second `@foreach`, when its defined.

Comment: @Qirel I then get back the first one from the API, which is a radio type

Comment: From your API response, the types and everything is empty? The data (and the dumps we asked for) is relevant for the question, so please add it. We're blindly guessing otherwise, and you won't get much help if we don't know what data you're dealing with.

Comment: code seems fine to me , there must be some issue in your data may be you are getting radio in all

Comment: I just edited the question with a dd from the api call with a question type textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that formOptions empty was in the questions where the type was textarea or checkbox. The foreach was supposed to be inside the radio if statement.
Thanks to everybody who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong object in the loop, you should be calling $answer, so change

```
@foreach($question['formOptions'] as $answer)
@if($question['type'] === "textarea" || $question['type'] === "paragraph")
     TextArea
@elseif($question['type'] === "checkbox")
     Checkbox
@elseif($question['type'] === "radio")
     Radio
@endif
@endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach($question['formOptions'] as $answer)
@if($answer['type'] === "textarea" || $answer['type'] === "paragraph"
     TextArea
@elseif($answer['type'] === "checkbox")
     Checkbox
@elseif($answer['type'] === "radio")
     Radio
@endif
@endforeach
```

Because the way you're doing it, you're only calling the FIRST instance of the loop, at $question, as its an array. But $answer is a specific object in the array for the foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you but $answer doesn't have a type

Comment: loop just $question then, as question has a type right?

Comment: Yes $question has a type, that is also what my code was based on.

Comment: can you maybe try to dd($question) and show us what you get there?

Comment: I did, It doesn't seem to like if I do that and just gives an error in the helper.php from laravel

Comment: put a dd below here `@foreach($category['formQuestions'] as $question)` {{dd($question}}.what was teh error from helper.php btw?

Comment: The dd doesn't really help, it gives the first one which is a type radio.
Sorry I can't trigger the error again, forgot where or when I got it and at this point there has so much happened in my code

Comment: wait if all of the have a type of radio, that's teh data you're getting, so returning radio to you is correct??

Comment: Nope, there are types of checkbox and textarea. I checked in the first dd for the whole API call. But because of reasons I am not allowed to post the whole dd. I am now checking with a dd to a certain part of the array to get the textarea type

Comment: ok mate, so basically, your looping is wrong, as you're only returning the one instance where all types are radio, as from what you told me, when you dd($category['formQuestions'] in which you derive $question from, all the arrays have a type of radio, your loop is only detecting this

Comment: I just edited my question to include a dd form a question with textarea

Answer (score 0):

can you changed your code

from

```
@if($question['type'] === "textarea" || $question['type'] === "paragraph")
```

into

```
@if($question['type'] == "textarea" || $question['type'] == "paragraph")
```

and check...

if you're using '===' it will check the values as well as the type.

Comment: I just tried that, it didn't do much for the result